# Does C++20 change how customization points should be written?

Tags: c++, c++20, argument-dependent-lookup

I was reading this [blogpost](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/03/19/customization-points-for-functions/) about the trouble of customization points in C++17, so I wonder if there are any changes in C++20 regarding this.

I am only concerned about language changes allowing me to write my library nicer, I presume there were no changes to `std::` due to backward compatibility reasons.

To make question self contained: here is my bad recap of problems mentioned in post:

- ADL dance solution is easy to get wrong(eg. calling `std::swap` instead of using `std::swap; swap(a,b);`,
- proper solution uses ugly boilerplate including priority inheritance trick `template<size_t I> struct priority_tag : priority_tag<I-1> {}; template<> struct priority_tag<0> {};`

Comment: One change is that specializing standard function templates is no longer allowed.  I didn't see that mentioned.

Comment: "Everyone should have [`priority_tag`] in their codebase somewhere." I don't think that's remotely true, I don't think it's even the right solution to what he's doing in the post. [`first_of`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/first_of.html) is more explicit, extensible, and typically terser.

Comment: @Barry I can not comment on present, but HOF not in boost at time of post: Version 1.67.0

April 14th, 2018 20:37 GMT
New Libraries: Contract, HOF.

Answer (score 3):

Pre-C++20, "customization point" was an informal idiom based around ADL that various parts of the C++ standard library would sometimes make use of. C++20 created a more formal idiom, with a much more direct kind of implementation.

But C++20's proper customization point concept is rather incompatible with the pre-C++20 idiom. So it creates new customization points that operate under its new rules: `std::ranges::begin/end`, `std::ranges::size`, etc.

The nature of C++20 customization point is such that you could have used the idiom in pretty much any version of C++. C++20's concepts make writing the customized version easier, but you could use some from of SFINAE in most C++ versions to accomplish basically the same thing.

[C++20 customization points](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/customization.point.object) are function objects, not regular template functions. As such, you cannot overload the function itself. You can customize a customization point either with a member function or with an ADL-accessible function, both of which must use the required name and interface. But this also means that you can't customize a non-user-defined type; the customization point type itself must provide any overloads for such functions.

The principle incompatibility between the two is in invoking the customization point, not so much in how you customize it. There's no need for the `using` dance.

Comment: It would be really nice to see a simple version of a customization point outside of the standard library.  That is, if I am a library author and want to develop a customization point for library users, what should that look like?